# scheme - recursive function of lists

Tags: scheme

I have this program:

```
(define scale-tree
  (lambda (tree factor)
    (map (lambda (sub-tree)
           (if (list? sub-tree)
               (scale-tree sub-tree factor)
               (* sub-tree factor)))
         tree)))

(scale-tree (list 1 (list 2 (list 3 4) 5) (list 6 7))
10)
```

How does this code work? First, we give it the whole list as parameter `(list 1 (list 2 (list 3 4) 5) (list 6 7))`, and in the first call, the `(lambda (sub-tree)` gets the `(list 1 (list 2 (list 3 4) 5) (list 6 7))` as parameter. For that, we call `(scale-tree sub-tree factor)` with `(list 1 (list 2 (list 3 4) 5) (list 6 7))` again. When does the list reduce?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember what `map` does - it applies a function to every element of a list. So on the first call, this function:

```
(lambda (sub-tree)
           (if (list? sub-tree)
               (scale-tree sub-tree factor)
               (* sub-tree factor)))
```

is being applied to the elements of your list: `1`, `(list 2 (list 3 4) 5)`, and `(list 6 7)`. And so on in the recursive calls.